# Regex validating string parameters when using ``%`` formatting in python

Tags: python, regex

In python you can format parameters using `%`-formatting like that:

```
"Foo %(bar)" % {"bar": baz}
```

I use some parameters like `%(name)s` for string rendering in Python (I am coding an auto mail apps) and I dont know how to evaluate it before using because if the user input the wrong parameter such as %(names or %names or %name)s or %%name()s or something like that, the apps will comes to error.

Comment: post some examples for valid and invalid strings.

Comment: So there are valid: `%(foo)`, `%(bar)` but not `%(foo)s`, `%(foo`, `%foo` etc?

Comment: Only string in form of %(something)s is valid. Note that something can contains "%(" or ")s" but not both

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches the "correct" input, eg `%(foo)s`:

```
^%\(\w+\)s$
```

This allows any "word" char for the name. To restrict the "name" part to just lowercase letters (as your examples all are):

```
^%\([a-z]+\)s$
```

Comment: Op says the string in the middle can contain `%( ` or `)s` but not both

Comment: @Smac89 I think English is not the OP's first language. Examples of bad input in question suggest this is what he wants.

Comment: @Bohemian: Smac89 is right. I also need to test that case. Sorry for not mentioning in the questions. Any suggestion?

Comment: But your comment says "Only string in form of %(something)s is valid". Please clarify what is valid and what is not valid by posting examples of each in your question.